# how to make cronjob to run at 6 am except sunday

Tags: cron

how to set cron to run at 6 am daily except sunday ?

tried using this:

```
0 6 * * 1-6 /path to script
```

but it executes at 6 am and at 11:30am.

Is it correct to use 1-6 for day of week ?

Comment: The command is fine, check if you have other cronjobs to this script. It looks like you have others for the same script.

Answer (score 2):

from 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

```
day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
```